# Using Buffer Wizard in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, buffer

I am creating a model in ArcMap 10 and I need to use the Buffer Wizard tool to create multiple buffers within a polygon feature class. The problem is, I can't seem to place the Buffer Wizard within my model. I can place the Buffer or Multiple Ring Buffer command into my model, but they don't automatically populate a FromBufferDistance or ToBufferDistance value for each ring like the Buffer Wizard does. I need these values for a field calculator equation later in the model. I may be able to get by with just using the Multiple Ring Buffer tool, but it would be much more efficient to use the Buffer Wizard.

If I am unable to include the buffer wizard in my model, is there a way to run it in a script? This seems unlikely, but worth a try.

Comment: If you are prepared to dive in to Python, you could export the modelbuilder as a python script and then use a loop to make as many buffers as you want. Not an answer to your question, but it would be a useful direction to try out if you have time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Buffer Wizard (and other wizards like the GeoStatistical Wizard) is a UI functionality.

There is no scripting/programming API for it in any version of ArcGIS 9.x or 10.x, and since it is not a geoprocessing tool so it cannot be used in ModelBuilder.

Answer (score 5):

You could try using an iterator in ModelBuilder for buffering multiple distances.

[image]

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00400000001n000000.htm